# URL.createObjectURL in React Native

Tags: npm, react-native

I'm converting a web client into a React Native client. There is a function [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) which doesn't exist in RN. I wonder if there is an npm package which does the same.

Comment: If you reached this page for webRTC, check this question instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41798731/why-is-webrtc-remote-video-source-generated-by-url-createobjecturl