# Why is WebRTC remote video source generated by URL.createObjectURL

Tags: webrtc

In [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/WebRTC_Basics), it uses `URL.createObjectURL` to set the video source. (This is the code to answer a call).

```
var offer = getOfferFromFriend();
navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, function(stream) {
  pc.onaddstream = e => video.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.stream);
  pc.addStream(stream);

  pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer), function() {
    pc.createAnswer(function(answer) {
      pc.setLocalDescription(answer, function() {
        // send the answer to a server to be forwarded back to the caller (you)
      }, error);
    }, error);
  }, error);
});
```

I expected video.src to be the address to retrieve the remote video. So it should be fixed and given by the other side of the connection (whoever initiated the call). But the value of `URL.createObjectURL` is generated on the answerer's side, and it event depends on when the function is called. How it can be used to get the remote video stream?

Edit:
The result of `URL.createObjectURL` looks like blob:http://some.site.com/xxxx-the-token-xxxx. With this string, how does the video component know where to load the remote stream? Is there a hashmap of {url:stream} stored somewhere? If so, how does the video component access the hashmap?

A stream object does store a token string, which you can get with `stream.toURL`. But it is different from the result of `URL.createObjectURL`. The value of `URL.createObjectURL` depends on time. If you call it twice in a row, you get different values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`URL.createObjectURL(stream)` is a hack. Stop using it. Efforts are underway to [remove it](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-main/issues/404).

Use [`video.srcObject = stream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject) directly instead. It is standard and well-implemented.

This assignment of a local resource should never have been a URL in the first place, and is a red herring to understanding how WebRTC works.

WebRTC is a transmission API, sending data directly from one peer to another. No content URLs are involved. The remote `stream` you get from `onaddstream` is a local object receiver side, and is the live streaming result of the transmission, ready to be played.

The documentation you read is old and outdated. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll fix it. It has other problems: you should call setRemoteDescription *immediately*, not wait for the receiver to share their camera, otherwise incoming candidates are missed. Instead of the code you show, do this:

```
pc.onaddstream = e => video.srcObject = e.stream;

function getOfferFromFriend(offer) {
  return pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer))
    .then(() => navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}))
    .then(stream => {
      pc.addStream(stream);
      return pc.createAnswer();
    })
    .then(answer => pc.setLocalDescription(answer))
    .then(() => {
      // send the answer to a server to be forwarded back to the caller (you)
    })
    .catch(error);
}
```

It uses `srcObject`, avoids the deprecated callback API, and won't cause intermittent ICE failures.

Comment: Thank you jib! This helped me narrow down the causes to my problem. But I still cannot figure out my original problem. Could you pls take a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41917545/3838949)? My iceConnectionState jumps from `checking` to `closed`. I'm not sure what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because a WebRTC connection involves several steps and what you get from such a connection is a stream. But the `src` property of the `video` tag does not accept a stream, but a URL. And this is the way to "convert" a stream to a URL.

Comment: I understand you need a URL, but I don't understand why the URL is generated this way. I'm in a situation where I need to write `URL.createObjectURL` myself because it is not available in React Native. So I tried to use `stream.toURL`, which produce a token different from what  `URL.createObjectURL` produce. It seems the video component cannot get the remote video properly with this token. The value of `stream.toURL` actually make more sense to me because it doesn't depend on time.

Comment: The result of `URL.createObjectURL` looks like `blob:http://some.site.com/xxxx-the-token-xxxx`. With this string, how does the video component knows where to load the remote stream? Is there a hashmap of `{url:stream}` stored somewhere? If so, how does the video component access the hashmap?

Comment: This mapping is internal to the browser. I don't think you can access/control it in any way.

Comment: If this is the case, updating of this internal mapping can only happen when `URL.createObjectURL` is called. Sounds a pretty weird side effect...

Comment: I think actually there's already a URL associated with each stream from the moment of its creation. That method only retrieves it for you.

Comment: It is so with `stream.toURL`, not with `URL.createObjectURL`. I applied `URL.createObjectURL` to the same stream twice in a row. The results are different. I think it uses time in its computation.