# RTCPeerConnection.iceConnectionState changed from checking to closed

Tags: webrtc

Following the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41837608/3838949) I'm trying to answer an audio call initiated with a Chrome browser from an iPhone simulator(with React Native).

A summary of the event sequence:

1. received call signal
2. got local stream
3. sent join call signal
4. received remote description(offer),
5. created PeerConnection
6. added local stream
7. received candidate
8. added candidate
9. 7 and 8 repeated 15 times (that is 16 times in total)
10. onnegotiationneeded triggered
11. signalingState changed into have-remote-offer
12. onaddstream triggered
13. the callback function of setRemoteDescription was triggered, created answer.
14. signalingState changed into stable
15. iceconnectionstate changed into **checking**
16. onicecandidate triggered for the first time.
17. emited the candidate from 15
18. onicecandidate triggered for the 2nd time. The candidate is `null`
19. iceconnectionstate changed into **closed**

Step 7,8,9 may appear at different places after 6 and before 19.

I have been stuck on this problem for quite a while. I don't even know what to debug at this time. What are the possible causes of the closing of connection? I can post more logs if needed.

One observation is that the two `RTCEvent` corresponding to `iceconnectionstatechange` has the following properties:

`isTrusted:false`

The target RTCPeerConnection has

```
iceConnectionState:"closed"
iceGatheringState:"complete"
```

Here are my functions to handle remoteOffer and remoteCandidates:

```
WebRTCClass.prototype.onRemoteOffer = function(data) {
  var ref;
  if (this.active !== true) {
    return;
  }
  var peerConnection = this.getPeerConnection(data.from);
  console.log('onRemoteOffer', data,peerConnection.signalingState);

  if (peerConnection.iceConnectionState !== 'new') {
    return;
  }
  var onSuccess = (function(_this){
    return function(){
      console.log("setRemoteDescription onSuccess function");
      _this.getLocalUserMedia((function(_this) {
          return function(onSuccess,stream) {
            peerConnection.addStream(_this.localStream);
            var onAnswer = (function(_this) {
              return function(answer) {
                var onLocalDescription = function() {
                  return _this.transport.sendDescription({
                    to: data.from,
                    type: 'answer',
                    ts: peerConnection.createdAt,
                    description: {
                      sdp: answer.sdp,
                      type: answer.type
                    }
                  });
                };
                return peerConnection.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(answer), onLocalDescription, _this.onError);
              };
            })(_this);
            return peerConnection.createAnswer(onAnswer, _this.onError);
          }
        })(_this)
      );
    }
  })(this);
  return peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data.description),onSuccess,console.warn);
};
```

---

```
WebRTCClass.prototype.onRemoteCandidate = function(data) {
  var peerConnection, ref;
  if (this.active !== true) {
    return;
  }
  if (data.to !== this.selfId) {
    return;
  }
  console.log('onRemoteCandidate', data);
  peerConnection = this.getPeerConnection(data.from);
  if ((ref = peerConnection.iceConnectionState) !== "closed" && ref !== "failed" && ref !== "disconnected" && ref !== "completed") {
    peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data.candidate));
  }
};
```

Comment: I suspect that [react-native-webrtc](https://github.com/oney/react-native-webrtc) works slightly different from the original webrtc package. But I'm very new to this, so it is also possible that I'm not following the right track of webrtc protocol

Comment: Are the simulator and browser in same network? Are you using any STUN or TURN servers in createpeerconnection? Do you have ios or chrome libjingle logs?

Comment: The simulator and browser are in the same network (127.0.0.1). The peerconnection was created with STUN server set to `stun:stun.l.google.com:19302`. I'm not sure what is libjingle log or how to turn it on. Could you pls point me a reference? I have some more detailed logs generated with the codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I call the following two functions one by one, then it will work.

```
peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data.description),onSuccess,console.warn);
(...definition of onAnswer ...)
peerConnection.createAnswer(onAnswer, this.onError);
```

My previous codes called `createAnswer` within the `onSuccess` callback of `setRemoteDescription`. That did work for the `react-native-webrtc` demo, but not with Rocket.Chat. Still don't fully understand it. But my project can move on now.