# How to get play video with getUserMedia object in Chrome

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia

I am working a web application using webrtc, as a first tutorial I am simply trying to access my camera and microphone via getUserMedia.

Here is my code:

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-inverse">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Demo WebRTC</a>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h2>Réccéption</h2>
                <video id="receiver-video" width="100%" height="400px" src=""></video>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h2>Envoi</h2>
                <video id="emitter-video" width="100%" height="400px" src=""></video>
                <p><button id="start">Démarrer la conversation</button></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


    </body>


</html>
```

app.js

```
document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener('click', function function_name(e) {

    navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia);

    navigator.getUserMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: true
    }, function(stream){

        let emitterVideo = document.querySelector('#emitter-video')
        emitterVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)
        emitterVideo.play()
    }, function() {})
})
```

With this code, I am able to access the camera and the microphone and to play the video in FireFox, but when i open it in Chrome, i can't play the video and the following error is thrown in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
Promise (async)
(anonymous) @ app.js:15
```

I am using Chrome Version 60.0.3112.90.

Comment: Are you using HTTP or HTTPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the tutorial you're using is not quite up to date. The usage of `window.URL.createObjectURL` is discouraged.

Meaning instead of

```
emitterVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)
```

you should use srcObject assignment

```
emitterVideo.srcObject = stream
```

If you'd like to stick with the tutorial though, there is another option. I'm assuming you're simply opening your index.html in the browser. If you'd instead serve it via `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` for example, it would also work.

Edit: some [more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41837608/980524) on `createObjectURL`

> URL.createObjectURL(stream) is a hack. Stop using it. Efforts are underway to remove it.
>
> Use video.srcObject = stream directly instead. It is standard and well-implemented.
>
> This assignment of a local resource should never have been a URL in the first place and is a red herring to understanding how WebRTC works.

Comment: Thank you so much WPP, it worked great.
I would like to ask about something, i would like to developp an application using a STUN server in order to connect two peers, or an HTTPS server, what I want to know, is there any available tutorials showing to developp a peer to peer application from scratch??

Comment: Hi, there are a lot of tutorials out there but I would recommend this one: https://deepstreamhub.com/tutorials/protocols/webrtc-intro/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i used this tutorial to understand the basics of using webrtc, i used the deepstreamhub server to complete tutorials, now what i would like to do, is to connect two real computers using a STUN server and i couldn't find any tutorial for a real application, can you please provide me with resources in order to connect two computers??